# Why are parentheses needed for try/catch block BufferedWriter

Tags: java, io, try-catch, bufferedwriter

I'm writing some code using java.io.BufferedWriter
the first thing I tried was:

```
    String filename = new String("test.txt");
    Charset charset = new Charset("US-ASCII");
    try {
        BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filename), charset);
        bw.write("hello");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

which outputted an empty test.txt
seeing an example, in the following format, I tried:

```
    String filename = new String("test.txt");
    Charset charset = new Charset("US-ASCII");
    try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(filename), charset)){
        bw.write("hello");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

which outputted a text file with the first line "hello".
What does this form mean, and why does it work while my first attempt did not?

Comment: I have never seen that form used before.

Comment: 2nd form is try with resources, and is only applicable in case of `Java 7`. However, your first form should also work fine. You certainly missed something else. You need to `flush` the output, or close the `bw`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is called "try-with-resources" in Java 7, your BufferedWriter will be closed automatically if you fixed it as

```
    try (BufferedWriter bw = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("filename"), StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)) {
        bw.write("hello");
    }
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score 1):

1-st option is syntactically correct.

I think you miss

```
bw.close();
```

after you done writting.

> Closes the stream, flushing it first.

Comment: You're right. using bw.close() in the first code block results in test.txt containing "hello".
Is there a reason it wasn't needed for the second code block to get the same effect? is the close() implicit in that case?

Comment: The try-with-resources syntax of Java7 does the close for you.